# What size hole do I need in masonry for an anchor that takes a 1/2" thread?

Tags: anchor, masonry, ladder

I bought these [ladder hangers](http://www.homedepot.com/buy/crown-bolt-1-2-in-wall-mounted-ladder-hanger-18012.html#.UO3F6ddgp0c) from Home Depot today. I have used anchors before, but I tend to not make the right size hole. What is the ideal size hole for an anchor that takes a 1/2" thread? How much smaller should the hole be than the anchor?

Comment: Generally the anchor manufacturer will tell you this - check the box/packaging it came in.

Comment: Your title mentions masonary anchor. The hanger you have pictured is for a hanger installed in wood. If it is infact going into wood a 5/16 inch pilot hole will surfice.

Comment: @mikes: So you can't use these for masonry? Not with the anchors?

Comment: @0A0D: What type of anchor would you be using with these hangers?

Comment: @pdd: Masonry...

Answer (score 2):

Those hangars are designed to go into wood, but you should be able to install into concrete using lag shields, just as you would use with a lag bolt. My only concern is that lag bolts have a standards and ratings, where this ladder hangar might be of unknown strength, and could simply shear off in the lag shield. I wouldn't park my car next to or beneath it.

The lag shield has a specified hole size required, which should be documented, such as [this one](http://www.fastenal.com/web/products/detail.ex?sku=51204).

Comment: I agree this how to attach the hanger to masonry, but if your wall is hollow concrete masonry, you can only expect good strength in solid grouted cells. The face shell wall thickness of the hollow portions is too shallow to support any reasonable load. Also be sure the length of the hanger's screw portion is at least as long as the specified minimum embedment of the shield.

Comment: agreed. To elaborate on my concern, lag shields are sized for a standard size lag screw. This hangar may not be close enough to a standard size to fit well. What I would use is a ladder hook that has holes in a mounting plate where you use your own fasteners. Then I would use tapcon or similar screws.